# How to understand the elasticsearch performance of 'Search Latency' on x-pack

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

I am testing the elasticsearch cluster perfomence. I use X-Pack to monitor the elasticseach performance.
The test program only search on one index.
Test program code :
[test program main logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgWoP.png)

The result on kibana :

[x-pack show about perform of 'Search Latency'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZRYK.png)

However , my program log , which print  how long time  each agg requrest consumes. 
[test program log about each agg requrest costs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpLxA.png)

The perform x-pack showed is difference with program log.
I don't know why , Ask for help !

Anthor, x-pack shows performance of my index resquest times, which is similar to my program log result.
[index performance of 'Request Time'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxuTL.png)